# Phone numbers in java

Tags: java, phone-number

I've got the code to put a seven letter phrase into a phone number. The hyphen is not returning in the correct spot. I really don't know how to fix this problem. It should return xxx-xxxx and if the phrase is xxxx xxx it returns xxxx-xxx. Please someone help me with this problem!

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Project1 {
  public static char getNumber(char letter) {
   char ret = 0;

    if (letter== 'A' || letter=='a' || letter== 'B' || letter=='b' || letter=='C' || letter=='c') {
      return '2';
    }
    else if (letter== 'D' || letter=='d' || letter== 'E' || letter=='e' || letter=='F' || letter=='f') {
      return '3';
    }
    else if (letter== 'G' || letter=='g' || letter== 'H' || letter=='h' || letter=='I' || letter=='i') {
      return '4';
    }
    else if (letter== 'J' || letter=='j' || letter== 'K' || letter=='k' || letter=='L' || letter=='l') {
      return '5';
    }
    else if (letter== 'M' || letter=='m' || letter== 'N' || letter=='n' || letter=='O' || letter=='o') {
      return '6';
    }
    else if (letter== 'P' || letter=='p' || letter== 'Q' || letter=='q' || letter=='R' || letter=='r'|| letter=='S' || letter=='s') {
      return '7';
    }
    else if (letter== 'T' || letter=='t' || letter== 'U' || letter=='u' || letter=='V' || letter=='v') {
      return '8';
    }
    else if (letter== 'W' || letter=='w' || letter== 'X' || letter=='x' || letter=='Y' || letter=='y' || letter=='Z' || letter=='z') {
      return '9';
    }
   if (letter == ' ')
     return '-';
   return ret;
  }




  public static void main (String[] arg) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a 7 letter phrase: ");
    String number = input.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      System.out.print(getNumber(number.toUpperCase().charAt(i)));
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `The hyphen is not returning in the correct spot.`?

Comment: *It should return xxx-xxxx and if the phrase is xxxx xxx it returns xxxx-xxx.* what does it mean?

Comment: if the phrase is xxxx xxx it should returns xxxx-xxx?

Comment: If this is in `java`, why not use a `switch` control statement?... It makes your code condensed and you can use `case stack`s instead!

Comment: @Unihedron: what about `String[] p = new String[]{"abc","def",..}; for (int i = 0; i < p.length; ++i) if (p[i].indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(letter)) != -1) return i+2;`

Comment: I'm trying to get the numbers to look like 123-4567. If I type in call home it displays like 1234-567. I need it to look like 123-4567. The hyphen has to go after the 3rd number.

Comment: @user3822460: the position of the `-` doesn't depend on the implementation of `getNumber` but just on its input. Provide a different input.

Comment: @user3822460 Why you do `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      System.out.print(getNumber(number.toUpperCase().charAt(i)));
    }` then?...

Comment: Your code is just replacing spaces with hyphens - if the input string contains space on 4th position, the output will contain hyphen also on 4th position (not on the 3rd).

Comment: @user3822460 if you type "call home", of course the hyphen is going to be in 5th place, **that's where your space is**. And it's one number short because it's looping through the first 8 characters, space included. If you want the hyphen always in 4th position, you'll have to program more code, because your code isn't made for that at all.

Comment: @Unihedron and why do you check for lowercase letters if you uppercase the string before passing it to the function?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need to import `java.lang.*`. This package is automatically imported.

Comment: @Unihedron I wasn't referring to you, but to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution to your problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Project1 {
    public static char getNumber(char letter) {
        char ret = 0;
        if( letter < 'A' )
        {
            ret = '0';
        }
        else if( letter < 'D' )
        {
            ret = '2';
        }
        else if( letter < 'G' )
        {
            ret = '3';
        }
        else if( letter < 'J' )
        {
            ret = '4';
        }
        else if( letter < 'M' )
        {
            ret = '5';
        }
        else if( letter < 'P' )
        {
            ret = '6';
        }
        else if( letter < 'T' )
        {
            ret = '7';
        }
        else if( letter < 'W' )
        {
            ret = '8';
        }
        else if( letter <= 'Z' )
        {
            ret = '9';
        }
        else
        {
            ret = '0';

        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( "Please enter a 7 letter phrase: " );
        String number = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for( int i = 0, j = 0; j < number.length() && i < 7; j++ )
        {
            char c = number.charAt(j);
            if( c != ' ' )
            {
                if( i == 3 )
                {
                    buff.append( '-' );
                }
                buff.append( getNumber( c ) );
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( buff );
    }
}
```

Key points:

- There is no need to check for lower case if the alpha characters are guaranteed to be uppercase.
- There is no need to uppercase the input string on each iteration of the loop. Do it once at the beginning.
- I'm ignoring spaces, and always adding a hyphen before I print position 3 (ie the fourth character).
- `char`s can be compared just like numbers, using ranges. This simplifies the amount of code quite a bit (ie. each letter within a range doesn't need to be written down).

Comment: This doesn't add a hyphen anywhere :/

Comment: And as studro silently reaches into his bag to get out his shiny new compiler, hurtling through space is a 10km wide meteorite heading towards New York City

Comment: Yeah I did all that. It complied on my computer once I fixed those. Still no hyphen though

Comment: Please enter a 7 letter phrase: 
 [get loan]
4385626

Comment: String number = input.nextLine();
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for( int i = 0, j = 0; j < number.length() && i < 7; j++ )
        {
            char c = number.charAt(j);
            if( c != ' ' )
            {
                if( j == 3 )
                {
                    buff.append( '-' );
                }
                buff.append( getNumber( c ) );
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( buff );
    }
    }

Comment: The most important thing is though: do you understand it?

Comment: Suggesting an edit probably would have taken as much time as leaving that comment.

Comment: @studro 1-character edits doesn't really work that well, plus I wasn't able to find any grammatical mistakes to correct.

Answer (score 1):

> It should return xxx-xxxx and if the phrase is xxxx xxx it returns xxxx-xxx. Please someone help me with this problem!

Here you go! A bit of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) is always good for the soul:

```
{
    String number = input.nextLine();
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // Buffer the sequence.
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      builder.append(getNumber(number.toUpperCase().charAt(i)));
    if (builder.toString().getCharAt(2) != '-') // If the format isn't correct, fix it
      System.out.println(builder.toString().replaceFirst("(...)(.).(...)", "$1-$2$3"))
    }
}
```

---

> [As seen from CSᵠ's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24667115/phone-numbers-in-java/24668230?noredirect=1#comment38248517_24668230), you can use the following universal regex instead, such that the section becomes:

```
builder.toString().replaceFirst("^\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d)\\D*(\\d)\\D*$", "$1$2$3-$4$5$6$7");
```

> **Edit:** Updated regex as [`\N` backreferences does not work in Java.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/25767/2014/7/10)

Comment: Lol, an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: @studro Right - not really the most efficient since this uses a bit of regex, and I'm sure some string manipulation experts will throw another answer soon. :)

Comment: How would I only make the last output show up? Thank you for your help btw

Comment: @user3822460 Define "_the last output_"?

Comment: Were it only shows 123-4567. The output in this situation has to have the hyphen after the third number. The example I was given was CALL HOME would display as 225-5466. And GET LOAN would be displayed as 438-5626.

Comment: I deleted the if = " " return "-" because it was only doing the hyphen in the spaces. I guess my big question is how do I get the hyphen after the 3rd number.

Comment: Universal RegEx (for 7 digits): Replace `^\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*$` with `\1\2\3-\4\5\6\7`

Comment: @CSᵠ Nice! But since this is Java, shouldn't we use `$1$2$3-$4$5$6$7` instead?